# Understanding IP address ranges

Tags: geoip

I'm somewhat of a noob, so please be kind. I'm building a local IPv4 database but am having difficulty understanding something.

Here are two IP block examples:

- 50.131.150.0/25
- 50.131.150.128/25

I understand that these represent ranges, but how so? I don't know what 0/25 and 128/25 represent. If I have the IP 50.131.150.42, which block does it belong to?

Comment: This should be in the networking forum...  Also, you just need to search for IP subnetting tutorial and nobody here can write something new that's not already out there on this subject.

Comment: The `/25` is the slash of the address, basically the width of the subnet mask.

Comment: Try this http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/the-slash-after-an-ip-address-cidr-notation

Comment: Thanks for your help. So which block would 50.131.150.42 belong to? The first or second?